# How can I find the next element (or elements) of my e.target?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

The grids div sample.

```
            <div class="gameBoard">
               <div class="grid">1</div>
               <div class="grid">2</div>
               <div class="grid">3</div> 
               <div class="grid">4</div>
               <div class="grid">5</div>
               <div class="grid">6</div> 
               <div class="grid">7</div>
               <div class="grid">8</div>
               <div class="grid">9</div> 
               <div class="grid">10</div>
            </div>
```

So if the grid with the 1 is being hovered over, I want to target the one with 2,3,4 and upto 5 at maximum.

If the user is dragging the ships destroyer/submarine, I want to target the
current div and the next div.

if ship is cruiser, current div plus next two div.
if ship is battleship, current div plus next three div.
if ship is carrier, current div plus next four div.

const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');

```
grids.forEach(el => {
el.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
      // Find the next few dom elements that comes after e.target
   });
});
```

The grids here represent a 10*10 grid in the dom which are just divs.
When I hover over certain divs, I want to be able to get the next few divs that comes after the current div. I have tried closest() but that does not work in this particular situation.

What I'm trying to do is to use drag & drop to place ships in my grid. So if the user is dragging the "destroyer" or the "submarine", I want to be able to get the current e.target and the next divs. If the user is dragging the "Carrier", I want to be able to get the current e.target and the next four divs cuz the size of the carrier is 5.

Comment: `el.querySelector(".classOfChild");` is the vanillajs equivalent of jQuery's `$(el).find(".classOfChild");` https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: you can use the `querySelector` method on any dom element, not just the `document` object.
You basically retrieved all `.grid` elements using  `document.querySelectorAll`. Now that you have a collection of elements, you can drill down the dom using again `querySelector` on `el`

Comment: But what will I use as the selector ?? el.querySelector(???)

Comment: Are they siblings? How are the elements laid out? Is it just the next ones in `grids`?

Comment: Yes, as in <div class='parent"> <div>child</di><div>child</div></div>

Comment: Oh, I get it now (I thought you knew the children elements classes beforehand). In this case, you can get all the children of the dragged element using `el.children;` that will return a `collection` which is iterable in different ways: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children

Comment: @GrafiCode please read the question carefully. The eventListener is set for each `grid` item, so no `children` present there. OP want to get the neighbour elements of a div if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you are right cloned. I have no need of children of dragged elements. If I am hovering over a div, I want to target the next (or next 5) sibling div  at max.

Comment: if this is the markup `<div class='parent"> <div>child</di><div>child</div></div>` then all divs are children of `.parent`... Since `e.target` is a DOM element itself, you can still retrieve all children using `e.target.children;`

Comment: if they actually are siblings, then you can use `e.target.nextElementSibling` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling

Comment: But i'm not trying to retrieve children of e.target. Im trying to retrieve the sibling. Can you give me a code sample of what you are trying to communicate please.

Comment: @Rabten, just for the record I don't think grabbing sibling nodes is the correct way to implement a Battleship clone. Plus, you're going to have a lot of trouble implementing vertical ships. It would be much easier to handle ALL of the view logic on the JavaScript side, and THEN render your view based on that data.

Comment: Hey, GrafiCode, it works now. Thanks to you and all who helped.

Comment: glad it worked, sorry for all the confusion. check the answer provided by @epascarello , it's super clean

Comment: @Phil I suppose but I tried doing that but can't code any logic without a UI. idk, im doing the odin project and felt very unintuitive writing logic for a game without a UI. anywys thanks for you advice. Ill just see how it goes for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index and get the next elements in the array

```js
const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cell'));

cells.forEach((el, index) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    const nextSiblings = cells.slice(index+1);
    console.log(nextSiblings);
  });
});
```

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can use DOM methods

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
grid.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let cell = e.target.closest(".cell");
  if (!cell) return;
  const siblings = [];
  while (cell = cell.nextElementSibling) {
    siblings.push(cell);
  }
  console.log(siblings);
});
```

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Used nextSiblingElement

```
grids.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
        //if (currentShipLength === 2) {
            const one = e.target;
            const two = e.target.nextElementSibling;
            const three = two.nextElementSibling;
            const four = three.nextElementSibling;
            const five = four.nextElementSibling;

            console.log(one, two, three, four, five);
        //};
    });
});
```